# Python csv writing error - string indices must be integers, not str

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract links from a website based on a search term and write them into a csv file. The file gets created but the links are not written in that. I get the error - string indices must be integers, not str.

Unable to figure out my mistake.

```
from pprint import pprint
import requests
import lxml
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_url_for_search_key(search_key):
    base_url = 'http://www.marketing-interactive.com/'
    response = requests.get(base_url + '?s=' + search_key)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "lxml")

    return [url['href'] for url in soup.findAll('a', {'rel': 'bookmark'})]

pprint(get_url_for_search_key('digital marketing'))
with open('ctp_output.csv', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for url in get_url_for_search_key('digital marketing'):
           writer.writerows( url['href'] )
```

Comment: At which line does the error occur? Please post the full traceback.

Comment: The error occurs in the last line -   writer.writerows( url['href'] )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function returns list with url as strings in them.
so you don't need url['href'] as it has already been taken care in your function.

Try

```
writer.writerows( url )
```

instead of:

```
writer.writerows( url['href'] )
```

I don't know how csv module work but you don't need csv here

try:

```
with open('ctp_output.csv', 'w') as f:
    f.write('\n'.join(get_url_for_search_key('digital marketing')))
```

Comment: Thanks.I tried that. Data is written into the csv file but each cell has only one letter. How do I get each cell to accommodate one link?

Comment: Got this - TypeError: 'encoding' is an invalid keyword argument for this function.